# how to connect to docker images within the same network?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, networking

I am trying to connect my node JS application to my mongoDB without using the ip address. The strategy which I have read up is that I must have both the containers in the same network.

My node JS application looks as below

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var PORT = 4000;

// REQUIRE MIDDLEWARE
var instantMongoCrud = require('express-mongo-crud'); // require the module



mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/user');

var options = { //specify options
    host: `localhost:${PORT}`
}

//USE AS MIDDLEWARE
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // add body parser
app.use(instantMongoCrud(options)); // use as middleware

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('started');
})
```

I have run my database mongodb and attached it into a network called nodenetwork.

I then did a build of my docker application as below:

```
docker build -t sampleapp:v1 . &&  docker run --net container:mongodb sampleapp:v1
```

the app runs correctly from the console output. However, I cannot access it via my browser.

I understand that it is because I must expose the port 4000 when i do a docker run as I had done before.

However, the issue is that when I tried to run like this instead

```
docker build -t sampleapp:v1 . &&  docker run -p 4000:4000 --net container:mongodb sampleapp:v1
```

it throws me: docker: Error response from daemon: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode.

AS such, my question how do I modify this command and is this the best way?

Comment: `localhost` always means "this container".  You do not need to expose anything and you do not specifically need a `-p` option, but you do need to `docker network create` something and use `docker run --net` to attach both containers to that network.

Comment: Hi david, \ if we dont enable port 4000 we cannot serve the app. I tried running without 4000 and it didnt work. i.e docker run <image id> without the port. As such, should we not expose the port ? if not how do we do it then

I did this docker run e22b44e3ffea --net container:mongodb -p 4000:4000 

but it keeps telling me 

ocker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"--net\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled

Do u have any idea?

Comment: Docker-specific options like `--net` need to go _before_ the image name.

Comment: didnt work also. docker run  --net container:mongodb -p 4000:4000 e22b44e3ffea

Says docker: Error response from daemon: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode.
See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling your application that mongodb will be accesible on `localhost` but it won't, as `localhost` will be the application container unless you're running it with `--net=host` and your mongodb container is exposing the `27017` port or is running on `--net=host` as well.

You could create a docker network and connect both containers (mongodb and app) to it.

Example:

```
$ docker network create mynetwork --driver bridge
$ docker run -d --name mongodb --net=mynetwork bitnami/mongodb:latest
$ docker run -d --name app -p 4000:4000 --net=mynetwork sampleapp:v1
```

This will create a DNS record for mongodb with the same name of the container that will be resolvable from any container within your user-defined network.

Another solution will be to use docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: bitnami.mongodb:latest
  app:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
```

Place this in a file called docker-compose.yml in the same directory where the `Dockerfile` for sampleapp is and run `docker-compose up`

As docker-compose creates a user-defined network as well, you can access mongodb using the container DNS record.

In any of the cases, change your application to connect using the DNS provided by docker:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb:27017/user');
```

Read more about docker-compose and user-defined networks here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/